# Stream waiting and blocking other events using Bloc in Flutter while loading Firebase snapshots

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, bloc

I'm writing an application using Flutter, Firebase Firestore and the bloc pattern.

When the app opens I want to load some books from the firestore database, for this purpose I have defined the following bloc code:

```
class EditorBloc extends Bloc<BookEvent, BooksState> {

  @override
  BooksState get initialState => BooksLoading();

  EditorBloc();

  Stream<BooksState> _loadBooks() async* {
    final CollectionReference bookPostRef = Firestore.instance.collection('books');
    try {
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = bookPostRef.snapshots();
      await for (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot in stream) {
        List<Book> remoteBooks = List();
        for (var documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.documents) {
          remoteBooks.add(Book.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot));
        }
        yield BooksLoaded(remoteBooks);
        // If I return here I can dispatch more events but not all the snapshots will be processed
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield BooksNotLoaded();
    }
  }

  Stream<BooksState> _saveBooks(Gym gym, Sector sector, BookHistory booksHistory) async* {
    // Some code
  }

  Stream<BooksState> _addBooks(Gym gym, Sector sector, BookHistory booksHistory) async* {
    // Some code
  }

  @override
  Stream<BooksState> mapEventToState(BooksState currentState, BookEvent event) async* {

    if (event is LoadBooks) {
      yield* _loadBooks(event.gym, event.sector);
    } else if(event is SaveBooks) {
      yield BooksLoading();
      yield* _saveBooks(event.gym, event.sector, event.booksHistory);
    } else if (event is AddBook) {
      yield* _addBooks(gym, sector, booksHistory)
    }
  }
}
```

When the application start I use the following code load the collection of books:

```
myBloc.dispatch(LoadBooks());
```

And I get notified when the books are loaded, but if I dispatch an other event like this one:

```
myBloc.dispatch(AddBook(newBook));
```

The event is never processed because the `EditorBloc` is still waiting for other snapshots in the method `_loadBooks`.

What shall I do to be able to dispatch other events?

Thanks!

Comment: You are intentionally listening to the changes in `LoadBooks`, right?

Comment: Yes, shall I? Not sure what is the way to go

Comment: I had the same problem and had to change my query from `ref.snapshots()` to `List<DocumentSnapShot> snapshots = await ref.get()` in order to get a Future. I then used `yield MyState(snapshots.map((snapshot) => myObject(snapshot)).toList());`

Comment: you already solve that?

Comment: Yes, in the bloc just call `dispatch(LoadBooksLoaded(remoteBooks));` instead of `yield` and in the `mapEventToState` method yield the corresponding state `BooksLoaded`

Comment: @JoanP.S can you post detailed code presenting the solution you found, please?

Comment: @JoanP.S it'd be very helpful for us if you share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can approach this is by listening to the Stream inside Future. Once that Future finishes, you can then start the other events.

```dart
Future<bool> whenFinishLoading(Stream<BooksState> source) async {
  await for (value in source) {
    // Define a condition expecting a value from Stream
    if (value) { 
      return value;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can then use Future `whenFinishLoading(Stream<BookState>)` waiting for it to finish to start the next Stream event.